# Posisition Absolute on Mpdf Kartik not working

Tags: php, css, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

Continue from the question [Yii2 mPdf Kartik: Set Height and Width Paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699037/yii2-mpdf-kartik-set-height-and-width-paper)

I have problem width position absolute on page footer.
[image]

I have set it up `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`
But page footer not in actual position.
The position should be like this:
[image]

this is my html code:

```
    <?php
$pages = 1;
$pageof = 1;
$totalPageof = ceil(count($model->details) /10);
$index = 0;
?>
<?php if(count($details) > 0) : ?>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
    <?php foreach($details as $detail) : 
        $index += 1;
    ?>
        <?php if($pages == 1) : ?>
        <div class="page-layout">
            <!-- HEADER -->
            <div class="page-header">
                <table class="table-header">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="font12" width="250"><strong>COMPANY NAME</strong></td>
                            <td class="font14" width="250"><strong>PROFORMA INVOICE</strong></td>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="font11" width="80">NO. PO</td>
                                        <td class="font11" width="10">:</td>
                                        <td class="font11"><?=$model->no_po?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="font11" width="250">
                                <p>COMPANY ADDRESS</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="font14" width="250"><?=$model->no_rorder?></td>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="font10" width="80"><?=(!empty($model->tgl_po)) ? date('d-M-Y', strtotime($model->tgl_po)) : NULL ?></td>
                                        <td class="font10"><?=(!empty($model->tgl_tempo)) ? 'DUE DATE '. date(' d-M-Y', strtotime($model->tgl_tempo)) : 'DUE DATE -' ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 0;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="font12" colspan="3">COMPANY PHONE</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="font10" width="60">NPWP</td>
                                        <td class="font10" width="10"></td>
                                        <td class="font10"><?=isset($model->distributor) ? $model->distributor->npwp : '-' ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="font10" width="60">SALESMAN</td>
                                        <td class="font10" width="10">:</td>
                                        <td class="font11"><?=isset($model->sales) ? (isset($model->sales->code)) ? $model->sales->code.'-'.$model->sales->name : $model->sales->name : '-' ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="font10" width="60">NOTICE</td>
                                        <td class="font10" width="10">:</td>
                                        <td class="font10"><?=isset($model->salesType) ? $model->salesType->name : '-' ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td rowspan="2" class="font12 grid-1">Kepada YTH</td>
                                            <td class="grid-2">
                                                <p class="font12"><?=isset($model->outlet) ? $model->outlet_code.' - '.$model->outlet->name : '-' ?></p>
                                                <p class="font12"><?=isset($model->outlet) ? $model->outlet->address : '-' ?></p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="font10 text-left" style="padding-left:180px;" colspan="2">
                                                            <span>
                                                                Phone &nbsp;&nbsp; <?=isset($model->outlet) ? $model->outlet->phone_1 : '-' ?>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="font10" width="200"><?=isset($model->outlet) ? $model->outlet->npwp : '-'?></td>
                                                        <td class="font10"><?='Page '. $pageof++ .' Of '. $totalPageof ?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /HEADER -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- /endif pages header -->
            <!-- CONTENT -->
            <?php if($pages == 1) : ?>
                <div class="page-content">
                    <table class="table-content">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>KODE#</th>
                                <th>PRODUK</th>
                                <th colspan="5">QUANTITY</th>
                                <th>PRICE</th>
                                <th>DISC</th>
                                <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!-- /endif pages content -->
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right"><?=(isset($detail['typeproduct'])) ? '*'. $detail['product_code'] : $detail['product_code']?></td>
                                <td><?=$detail['product_name']?></td>
                                <td><?=($detail['comp_1'] && $detail['zqty_1'] != 0) ? number_format($detail['zqty_1']).'.'.$detail['comp_1'] : ''?></td>
                                <td><?=($detail['comp_2'] && $detail['zqty_2'] != 0) ? number_format($detail['zqty_2']).'.'.$detail['comp_2'] : ''?></td>
                                <td><?=($detail['comp_3'] && $detail['zqty_3'] != 0) ? number_format($detail['zqty_3']).'.'.$detail['comp_3'] : ''?></td>
                                <td><?=($detail['comp_4'] && $detail['zqty_4'] != 0) ? number_format($detail['zqty_4']).'.'.$detail['comp_4'] : ''?></td>
                                <td><?=($detail['comp_5'] && $detail['zqty_5'] != 0) ? number_format($detail['zqty_5']).'.'.$detail['comp_5'] : ''?></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><?=(!is_null($detail['zsprice_1'])) ? number_format($detail['zsprice_1'], 0, ',', '.') : ''?></td>
                                <td class="text-right"></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><?=(!is_null($detail['zjum_j'])) ? number_format($detail['zjum_j'], 0, ',', '.') : ''?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- COUNTER ITEM -->
                            <?php if($pages == 10 || $index == count($details)) : ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /CONTENT -->
                <!-- FOOTER -->
                <?php if($totalPageof == ($pageof-1)) : ?>
                <div class="page-footer">
                    <table class="table-footer">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="grid-1">
                                    <p class="font9"><?=(!empty($model->keterangan)) ? '<i>##</i>'. $model->keterangan : NULL ?></p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="grid-2 text-right" width="200">
                                    <p class="font12"><strong><?=(!$model->post) ? '' : '### PENCETAKAN ULANG ##' ?></strong></p>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">Cetakan ke</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?= (!empty($model->post)) ? $model->print : 0 ?></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">Sub Total</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?=number_format($realJumlah['total_j'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">Total Pcode</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?= count($details) ?></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">Disc Inv</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?=number_format($realJumlah['disc_percent'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">Point</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?=number_format($realJumlah['disc_point'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">DPP</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?=number_format($realJumlah['dpp'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="4"></td>
                                                <td class="font9" width="60">PPN</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9 text-right"><?=number_format($realJumlah['ppn'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="4"></td>
                                                <td class="font10" width="60"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
                                                <td class="font10">:</td>
                                                <td class="font10 text-right"><strong><?=number_format($realJumlah['inv'], 0, ',', '.')?></strong></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="grid-1"></td>
                                <td class="grid-2 font10 money text-justify"><?=$realJumlah['terbilang']?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="grid-1">
                                    <p class="font10">Admin SPV Gudang Pengirim Outlet</p>
                                    <p class="font10">Produck yang sudah diterima harap diperiksa kembali</p>
                                    <p class="color-white">----------------------------------------------------</p>
                                    <p>----------------------------------------------------</p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="grid-2" style="padding-left: 80px;">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="font9">User</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9"><?=Yii::$app->user->identity->profile->user->username?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="font9">Printed</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9"><?= date('H:i:s', time()) ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="font9">on</td>
                                                <td class="font9">:</td>
                                                <td class="font9"><?=date('d/m/Y')?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- /FOOTER -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- /COUNTER ITEM -->
        </div>
    <?php
        $pages++;
        if($pages > 10)
            $pages = 1;
        endforeach;
    ?>
    <!-- /endforeach -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- /endif count -->
```

And this my css code:

```
/** page layout */
.page-wrapper {
  height: 13.6cm;
  width: 21.2cm;
}
.page-layout {
  height: 13.6cm;
  width: 21.2cm;
}
.page-footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
/** end page layout */
/** table style */
.table-header {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-header tbody tr td {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.table-header tbody tr td p {
  margin: 0;
}
.table-header tbody tr td table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-header tbody tr td table tbody tr td.grid-1 {
  width: 20%;
}
.table-header tbody tr td table tbody tr td.grid-2 {
  width: 80%;
}
.table-content {
  font-family: 'Couriere';
  width: 100%;
}
.table-content thead tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}
.table-content tbody tr td {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.table-footer {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-footer tbody tr td {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.table-footer tbody tr td p {
  margin: 0;
}
.table-footer tbody tr td.grid-1 {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  width: 70%;
}
.table-footer tbody tr td.grid-2 {
  width: 30%;
}
.table-footer tbody tr td.money {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.table-footer tbody tr td table {
  width: 100%;
}
/** end table style */
/** custom child */
.font9 {
  font-size: 9px;
}
.font10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.font11 {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.font12 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.font14 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
.color-white {
    color: #fff;
}
/** end custom child */
```

May be someone has experienced it, hopefully it can be helped.

Comment: please give your pdf html code

Comment: Hove done @vishuB, I just revised it above

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier to read and abstract away the parts that are not relevant to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @TriwahyuPamungkasPribadi Have you tried embedded or inline styles? Most of the styles in css won't work while generating a PDF.

Comment: Finally, I use another method, by reducing the remaining rows with existing rows